# ninja error: .../export_includes needed by .../import_includes

Tags: android

Trying to rewrite a 'normal' Makefile to Android.mk. Original file:

```
CPPFLAGS += -Iandroid_linux -D_HW_DONT_INCLUDE_CORE_


# HAL source files location
HAL_SRC_DIR := ../..

# include dirs
CPPFLAGS += -I$(HAL_SRC_DIR)/tools

# test application
TEST_MODULE := test-sensors-hal
TEST_MODULE_FILES := test-sensors-hal.cpp

OBJ_FILES := $(SRC_C_FILES:.c=.o) $(SRC_CPP_FILES:.cpp=.o)

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(MODULE) $(TEST_MODULE)

clean:
    -rm -f $(OBJ_FILES) $(MODULE) $(TEST_MODULE)

$(MODULE): $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@

$(TEST_MODULE): $(MODULE)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(TEST_MODULE_FILES) -ldl -lpthread -lstdc++ -o $@
```

Rewritten Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# InvenSense Sensors HAL
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -Iandroid_linux -D_HW_DONT_INCLUDE_CORE_

LOCAL_MODULE := test-sensors-hal
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -Werror
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DLOG_TAG=\"Sensors\"
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -O2
LOCAL_LDLIBS:= -ldl -lpthread -lstdc++

# include dirs
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES+= $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../tools

# source C files
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test-sensors-hal.cpp

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Error when running 'mm' in local folder:

```
ninja: error: 'out/target/product/msm8996/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libpthread_intermediates/export_includes', needed by 'out/target/product/msm8996/obj/EXECUTABLES/test-sensors-hal_intermediates/import_includes', missing and no known rule to make it
```

What does it mean and how to fix it?

(I have to add additional information before I can post this, but this basically sums up my question)

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question and maybe of those who end up here in the future. This error is basically ninja's version of 'library not found'. Turns out you shouldn't attempt to link pthread because it is part of bionic, Android's libc. The culprit was that the code contains 'pthread_cancel', which is not in NDK's pthread.

For my particular use case I couldn't care less about pthread_cancel, so removed and it builds. Closing down the application yields some error that is probably related to removing this.

Comment: FYI it has nothing to do with ninja. That's the AOSP build system.